# Kernel oops Oops: 80000005 on arm embedded system

Tags: linux-kernel, crash-dumps, omap, debug-backtrace

Please help me to solve this Oops. I use a 1 milli sec high resolution timer and installing it as a seperate module with "insmod". This fires every 1 ms and i have to do some task with this timer interrupt. There are other processes which does image transfer and i see ethernet driver interrupt appearing to send the image. This enet interrupt is having some high priority and looks like it is delaying the 1 ms timer interrupt above, but i am not sure.

I see the below Oops after running test for 3 to 3 hours. How to root cause this ?
please help.
The system is ARM omap, running Linux 2.6.33 cross compiled.

```
[root@user:/]# 
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 7eb52754
pgd = 80004000
[7eb52754] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 80000005 [#1] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/spi/spi/dev
Modules linked in: mod timermod mod2(P) mod3(P) mod4
CPU: 0    Tainted: P            (2.6.33_appl #1)
PC is at 0x7eb52754
LR is at walk_stackframe+0x24/0x40
pc : [<7eb52754>]    lr : [<8002d4dc>]    psr: a0000013
sp : 80395f10  ip : 80395f30  fp : 80395f2c
r10: 0000001f  r9 : 00000000  r8 : 87a25200
r7 : 878b0380  r6 : 80395f40  r5 : 80028374  r4 : 80395f30
r3 : 80000100  r2 : 80395f40  r1 : 80395f40  r0 : 80395f30
Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Control: 10c5387d  Table: 86fb0019  DAC: 00000017
Process swapper (pid: 0, stack limit = 0x803942e8)
Stack: (0x80395f10 to 0x80396000)
5f00:                                     8002bfa4 00000001 802c678c 87a25380
5f20: 80395f54 80395f30 8002bfe0 8002d4c4 80395f54 80395f30 8004998c 8002bfa4
5f40: 00000002 00000002 80395f6c 80395f58 8004998c 8002bfb0 80396ea8 80394000
5f60: 80395fa4 80395f70 802c678c 800498d0 8002b320 80023218 80398408 80021e10
5f80: 80394000 8002321c 80023218 80398408 80021e10 413fc082 80395fbc 80395fa8
5fa0: 8002b324 802c62fc 803f4cc8 803f5190 80395fcc 80395fc0 802c3ee4 8002b28c
5fc0: 80395ff4 80395fd0 8000897c 802c3e6c 800084fc 00000000 00000000 8002321c
5fe0: 10c53c7d 803c7630 00000000 80395ff8 80008034 80008754 00000000 00000000
Backtrace:
[<8002d4b8>] (walk_stackframe+0x0/0x40) from [<8002bfe0>] (return_address+0x3c/0x5c)
 r6:87a25380 r5:802c678c r4:00000001 r3:8002bfa4
[<8002bfa4>] (return_address+0x0/0x5c) from [<8004998c>] (sub_preempt_count+0xc8/0xfc)
[<800498c4>] (sub_preempt_count+0x0/0xfc) from [<802c678c>] (schedule+0x49c/0x4d8)
 r5:80394000 r4:80396ea8
[<802c62f0>] (schedule+0x0/0x4d8) from [<8002b324>] (cpu_idle+0xa4/0xbc)
 r9:413fc082 r8:80021e10 r7:80398408 r6:80023218 r5:8002321c
r4:80394000
[<8002b280>] (cpu_idle+0x0/0xbc) from [<802c3ee4>] (rest_init+0x84/0xa0)
 r4:803f5190 r3:803f4cc8
[<802c3e60>] (rest_init+0x0/0xa0) from [<8000897c>] (start_kernel+0x234/0x284)
[<80008748>] (start_kernel+0x0/0x284) from [<80008034>] (__enable_mmu+0x0/0x2c)
Code: bad PC value
---[ end trace 7e26218fd59f68a5 ]---
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
Backtrace:
[<8002db2c>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x114) from [<802c610c>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
 r6:fffffffc r5:0000000b r4:803c8518 r3:00000002
[<802c60ec>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x24) from [<802c6168>] (panic+0x58/0x130)
[<802c6110>] (panic+0x0/0x130) from [<80057330>] (do_exit+0x7c/0x6e0)
 r3:80394000 r2:00000000 r1:80395d28 r0:80348e90
[<800572b4>] (do_exit+0x0/0x6e0) from [<8002dfc0>] (die+0x290/0x2c4)
 r7:7eb52744
[<8002dd30>] (die+0x0/0x2c4) from [<8002f4d4>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x74/0x84)
 r7:80395ec8
[<8002f460>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x84) from [<8002f6bc>] (do_page_fault+0x1d8/0x1f0)
 r7:00000000 r6:80395ec8 r5:7eb52754 r4:80396ea8
[<8002f4e4>] (do_page_fault+0x0/0x1f0) from [<8002f794>] (do_translation_fault+0x20/0x80)
[<8002f774>] (do_translation_fault+0x0/0x80) from [<80029250>] (do_PrefetchAbort+0x44/0xa8)
 r6:7eb52754 r5:80398820 r4:00000005 r3:8002f774
[<8002920c>] (do_PrefetchAbort+0x0/0xa8) from [<80029d1c>] (__pabt_svc+0x5c/0xa0)
Exception stack(0x80395ec8 to 0x80395f10)
5ec0:                   80395f30 80395f40 80395f40 80000100 80395f30 80028374
5ee0: 80395f40 878b0380 87a25200 00000000 0000001f 80395f2c 80395f30 80395f10
5f00: 8002d4dc 7eb52754 a0000013 ffffffff
 r7:878b0380 r6:80395f40 r5:80395efc r4:ffffffff
[<8002d4b8>] (walk_stackframe+0x0/0x40) from [<8002bfe0>] (return_address+0x3c/0x5c)
 r6:87a25380 r5:802c678c r4:00000001 r3:8002bfa4
[<8002bfa4>] (return_address+0x0/0x5c) from [<8004998c>] (sub_preempt_count+0xc8/0xfc)
[<800498c4>] (sub_preempt_count+0x0/0xfc) from [<802c678c>] (schedule+0x49c/0x4d8)
 r5:80394000 r4:80396ea8
[<802c62f0>] (schedule+0x0/0x4d8) from [<8002b324>] (cpu_idle+0xa4/0xbc)
 r9:413fc082 r8:80021e10 r7:80398408 r6:80023218 r5:8002321c
r4:80394000
[<8002b280>] (cpu_idle+0x0/0xbc) from [<802c3ee4>] (rest_init+0x84/0xa0)
 r4:803f5190 r3:803f4cc8
[<802c3e60>] (rest_init+0x0/0xa0) from [<8000897c>] (start_kernel+0x234/0x284)
[<80008748>] (start_kernel+0x0/0x284) from [<80008034>] (__enable_mmu+0x0/0x2c)
```

=========================================

```
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

#define FIRST_MINOR 0
#define MINOR_CNT   1

static struct class *cl;
static struct cdev cdev;
static dev_t dev;
static u8 timer_expired = 0;
static wait_queue_head_t wq_head;

static struct hrtimer timer;

static ssize_t hr_read(struct file *f, char * __user buff, size_t cnt, loff_t *off)
{
    wait_event_interruptible(wq_head, timer_expired);
    timer_expired = 0;
    return 0;
}

static int hr_open(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
    ktime_t ktime;
        ktime.tv64 = 1E6L;
        hrtimer_start(&timer, ktime, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    return 0;
}   


static int hr_close(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
    if (hrtimer_cancel(&timer))
       printk(KERN_INFO "timercancelled\n");

    return 0;
}   

static struct file_operations hr_fops = {
    .read = hr_read,
    .open = hr_open,
    .release = hr_close
};

static enum hrtimer_restart timer_callback(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
    ktime_t ktime;
    u64 overrun;
    ktime.tv64 = 1E6L;
    //printk("KERN_INFO""Timer Expired");

    overrun = hrtimer_forward_now(timer, ktime);
    timer_expired = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&wq_head);
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}
#if 1

static int init_hrtimer(void)
{   
    ktime_t ktime;
    unsigned long delay_in_ms = 500L;
    printk(KERN_ERR "Timer being set up\n");

    ktime = ktime_set(0,delay_in_ms*1E6L);
    hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

    timer.function = &timer_callback;
    printk(KERN_ERR "Timer starting to fire\n");
    printk(KERN_ERR "in %ldms %ld\n", delay_in_ms, jiffies);

    if (alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, FIRST_MINOR, MINOR_CNT, "Hr Timer") < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    printk("Major Nr: %d\n", MAJOR(dev));

    cdev_init(&cdev, &hr_fops);

    if (cdev_add(&cdev, dev, MINOR_CNT) == -1)
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "hrtimer")) == NULL)
    {
        cdev_del(&cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return -1;
    }
    if (IS_ERR(device_create(cl, NULL, dev, NULL, "hrt%d", 0)))
    {
        class_destroy(cl);
        cdev_del(&cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return -1;
    }

    init_waitqueue_head(&wq_head);

    return 0;
}
#endif


static void clean_hrtimer(void)
{
    int cancelled = hrtimer_cancel(&timer);

    if (cancelled)
        printk(KERN_ERR "Timer still running\n");
    else
        printk(KERN_ERR "Timer cancelled\n");

     device_destroy(cl, dev);
     class_destroy(cl);
        cdev_del(&cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
}

module_init(init_hrtimer);
module_exit(clean_hrtimer);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

========================

I use the above code as a driver module and insert it with insmod. I expect this to fire every 1 ms and it works fine but once in a while when ehernet traffic is too high, it gives a kernel Oops as explained. Please check if the code is having any issues in it or not?

I checked the lsmod, and i see that all the 5 kernel modules (my own) are loaded between: 0x7f000000 to 0x7f02xxxx

```
mod at 0x7f020xxxx, 
timermod at 0x7f01xxx, 
mod2 at 0x7f01xxxx, 
mod3 at 0x7f00xxxx, 
mod4 at 0x7f000000.
```

There is no module loaded at oops address 0x7eb52754. I checked from /proc/kallsyms file to 
verify this. How to check the mapping of 0x7eb5xxxx in to the source file? Where else can i get the data for this on system.

Comment: This is most likely a consequence of your kernel having been compiled with `CONFIG_FRAMEPOINTER` (and/or `CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER`) but your module(s) without, since your `LR` is in `walk_stackframe`, which means the unwind code "jumped into nowhere". `ftrace` and its kernel-side config are very sensitive to those settings being correct and uniform across the kernel and all loadable modules.

Comment: Ashoka, Have you resolved the issue? 

I'm seeing similar problem on a 2.6.39 arm kernel. It looks the solution is to change scheduling from "CONFIG_PREEMPT=y" to "CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y". Do it from menuconfig so the related flags are also changed. 

If you have resolved your issue, how did you do it? If not can you try changing scheduling and let us know? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message, the code that caused this kernel panic resides at virtual address 0x7eb52754. Judging from the address (just below 0x8000000), I'm guessing this is the code segment of a kernel module - probably one of your own kernel modules.

To do a root cause analyses, load your (and all other) kernel modules in the same order as they were loaded when this panic occurred and observe their load address as printed by lsmod (or cat /proc/modules which is almost the same).

Using their code size and load address, calculate which module text segment resides at virtual address 0x7eb52754. The subtract 0x7eb52754 from the module load address.

What you will get is the offset into the module binary of the instruction that caused the panic.

Now use objdump on the kernel module binary and look for that offset, and check to which function it belong (this can also be done with add2line, if you have that too). This should point you to the function and even line number (if you have debug information) of the instruction that caused this panic.

good luck.

Comment: @ gbay: Thanks for the reply. Yes i have the small kernel module i used to fire the timer every 1 ms. I have pasted the code of that module. Please check the code and let me know if it is perfectly alright ?

Comment: I checked the lsmod, and i see that all the 5 kernel modules (my own) are loaded between: 0x7f000000  to 0x7f02xxxx

mod at 0x7f020xxxx, 
timermod at 0x7f01xxx, 
mod2  at  0x7f01xxxx, 
mod3  at  0x7f00xxxx, 
mod4  at  0x7f000000.

There is no module loaded at oops address 0x7eb52754. I checked from /proc/kallsyms  file to verify this.